Existing EASA modules 1 to 13, missing module 3, EASA or UK CAA
I have all EASA modules for B2 aside from module 3. I live in the UK, and obtained these modules from 2017 to 2020 at a Part 145. Due to some circumstances, I didn't do the module 3 (electric fundamentals) until now.
I'm aware I need module 3 to become qualified. Do I do this as UK CAA exam? Also, does the gap mean I have to redo all other modules under UKCAA? Thanks.
